# Prove or disprove that if the sum of the probabilities of three events is 1, then the events are mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, proof-writing

> Which of the following statements is true? If a statement is true,
>   prove it. If it is false, give a counterexample.
>
> If $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$, then the events A, B, and C are mutually
>   exclusive.

I started my proof with the theorem below:

$$P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) – P(AB) – P(AC) – P(BC) + P(ABC)$$

We know that $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$, so substituting that into the equation above:

$$P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = 1 – P(AB) – P(AC) – P(BC) + P(ABC)$$

Since $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$, then $P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = 1$. Therefore:

$$P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) = P(ABC)$$

I know that to prove these events are mutually exclusive, I have to show that $P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) = P(ABC)=0$. However, I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Comment: The reason is because the "theorem" is false.  Take, as a counterexample, the case of rolling $3$ six-sided dice , where a win is getting either a $5$ or a $6$.  Let $A$ be the event that you win the first throw, $B$ be the event that you win the second throw, and $C$ be the event that you win the third throw.  Then $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1$, and although the events are independent, they are certainly not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(A)=\frac 1  3$ and $B=C=A$ then $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$ but the events are not mutually exclusive.